# C - Declaring a function within a function and returning it

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have the following code:

```
ll_data_comp sh_program_comp(int pid) {
  int comp(void* d) {
    sh_program_t* p = d;
    return p->pid == pid;
  }
  return comp;
}
```

- Since `comp` is declared in `sh_program_comp`, does that mean it's declared on the stack?
- If so, does that mean there's potential for a seg fault if it's used after it's returned?
- If not, does that mean I have to free `comp` somewhere?

Comment: Definitely not on the stack, I bet the only thing that changes is the scope of the function name. Also, this could be a non-standard compiler extension.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: of course, `gcc -pedantic` reports `main.c:5:3: warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that's what I thought, thanks.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli is this a definitive answer? I shouldn't worry about seg faulting on or having to free the returned function?

Comment: The definitive answer is that it is invalid C. Don't do it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It is not invalid C. The C standard defines it as conforming code but not strictly conforming code.

Comment: s/invalid/non-standard/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C calling nested function inside another nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221210/c-calling-nested-function-inside-another-nested-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the following code:

And you have tagged your question  with `C99`. The following code is invalid - it's not possible to define a function within a block scope.

The code may be compiled with GNU gcc compiler with [Nested Functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) *extension* to the C language. But from the documentation:

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.

If you try to call `comp` function after `sh_program_comp`, a portal to hell will open. Please don't do it.

Comment: It is not invalid; the C standard defines it as conforming code.

Comment: Well, at least now we know where those nasal demons come from...

Answer (score 2):

[Nested functions are a GCC extension to C.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) According to the documentation, you can call the nested function from outside the scope of the containing function by passing a pointer to it, but that is supported only until the containing function exits. The variables of the containing function are visible to the nested function.

> … on the stack?

I expect the machine code for the nested function is put in the usual place for machine code, the “text” segment. There would be difficulties putting it on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged this with c99, but not any compiler. Note that according to c99 (and also earlier and later versions) this is not even valid C code. Or well, the C standard allows these extensions, but do not enforce them. But no C standard is applicable here.

But some *compilers* offers this *extension*. And because of this, the behavior of such an extension is entirely compiler dependent.

Furthermore, the C standard does not even say anything at all about the stack. Usually, for very practical reasons, local variables end up on the stack and dynamic allocation on the heap, but the C standard does not say anything. So even if this code were valid C, your question would still not be answerable in a general sense, since it's entirely up to the implementation.

Comment: This is not invalid C code. Per C 2018 4 7, “A *conforming program* is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.” Per 4 6, “… A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.” Thus, any extension that does not change the behavior of code that does not use extensions is conforming to the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not sure in what way I'm contradicting this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Better?

Comment: The statement “this is not even valid C code” is false. It is conforming code. The C standard does not even define “valid” or “invalid” as it applies to programs (although “invalid” is used in one non-normative footnote). It defines conforming and strictly conforming, and, by implication, non-conforming. Nested functions are not invalid (since that is not defined for C) and are not non-conforming. They are conforming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As it stands now, I think it's pretty clear what that sentence means when you put it in the context of the whole paragraph. The last sentence have the style of "oh well, what I just said is not 100% true, but"

Comment: Where do people get this idea that you are only supposed to write strictly conforming C and anything else is invalid? That has never been the intent of C or the C standard. Unlike Java, C was not designed as a language where a program would run the same way in every implementation. It was designed so the language itself could be easily ported to new platforms. Sure, there is a core language, and that makes it easy for programmers to program in it wherever it is. But it is intended to have extensions and customizations for various purposes. They are normal, expected, and desired, not invalid.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know. You have to ask them. I have nothing against people using extensions as long as they''re aware that they are using extensions.

Comment: But that is an idea you have and are spreading. You wrote “this is not even valid C code.” That is incorrect. C invites extensions. The success of C depended on extensions and customizations. It is conforming C code; it is valid.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, you tend to interpret things people write very literately. "It's not guaranteed to be compiled by a conforming compiler" does not have the same attention grabbing as "it's invalid". The first also tends to make people believe that this is just nerdy mumbo jumbo that you don't have to care about in real life.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In many cases people say *"It's not valid C. You're modifying a string literal, thus invoking UB"* when the more truthful answer would be *"The C standard does not say what would happen in this case, so it's either a compiler extension or a bug. I don't know of any compiler that has this extension, and since you're not stating that, I cannot for certain say that it's wrong. But I find it very likely that the segfault is caused by modifying a string literal. But please read your compiler manual to see if this extension is listed there."*

Comment: Just say it is a GCC extension to standard C instead of saying it is invalid. That is true, concise, clear, and does not spread false notions about “invalid” C. People do need to care about extensions in real life; they will encounter them and need to understand extensions are conforming, useful, expected, and desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil We've had this discussion before. I put more value in a post as a whole than that all sentences should necessarily be 100% correct, even if taken out of context. You seem to value the latter very high. You do you. I do I. I like your answers. They are often very informative, but sometimes I get the feeling of "get to the point". Sure, that first sentence is not completely correct, but 1) that's fixed in the next sentence, and 2) the important thing here is not if the C standard allows extensions or not, but just the simple fact that they are extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of functions **is a GCC extension (valid only for C)**  If you look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221210/c-calling-nested-function-inside-another-nested-function/66261222#66261222) you will read there why your function is not valid once the scope of it is finished (the containing function returning)  More if it accesses (or is used, as you use it here, and in the original answer) local data of the enclosing function, which doesn't exist once the enclosing function has finished.